# Camera Preview Issue - Preview becomes pixellated and distorted

Tags: android, android-camera, onresume, onpause

I am creating an application, part of which has a camera preview.

My problem is, if I hit home on the device and re open the app the camera is pixelated with purple lines running through it.  I had assumed that this was something to do with the onResume() / onPause() methods, but I in this I stop my preview and set the camera to null (below)

**ON RESUME**

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {

        //Registering the Listener
        super.onResume();
        manager.registerListener(this,
                manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                manager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        //Opening the Camera and Starting the Preview
        camera = Camera.open();
        startPreview();
    }
```

**ON PAUSE**

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        if(camera!=null)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            inPreview = false;

        }
    }
```

I have an option for the user to retake their pic, if the user tries to retake the image for a third time I face the same issue.  I don't know what the issue is, I obtained my camera code from

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java

With a little editing to suit my needs.

From reading and research it seems that my onPause and onResume are correct so this may not be the problem...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: if you remove startPreview() then what happens??

Comment: That code is a bit old. That being said, I never experienced the behaviors you describe, which may be tied to your specific device model (whatever it is). If you can reproduce the problem with [my CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), let me know what the device model is, so I can do further research.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will have a look at that library but in the mean time just to let you know the device I'm using is a Samsung Nexus 10

Comment: Well, I am definitely not seeing that behavior on my Nexus 10 with the CWAC-Camera demo project (lucky for me that I happened to have the N10 running and the app installed!).

Comment: @ArmaanStranger the same issue I'm afraid

Comment: @CommonsWare at the risk of sounding cheeky, do you have your old code to test on the device?  I've just been working on touch to focus, I haven't had a chance to try to test your newer version

Comment: @CommonsWare (just an after thought) in the getBestPreviewSize method I have added camera.setDisplayOrientation(90), this was just to lock it to portrait, so my view is portrait and when i hit the home button on the n10 and re open the app, the orientation is back to landscape with the view pixellating and with purple lines going through..

Comment: Um, you linked to my old code in your question. I am not sure what other code you might be referring to. That project (and the `Camera/Picture/` project in the same repo) were my first forays into supporting `Camera`.

Comment: sorry, that's the code I was referring to, your first camera support, I'm wondering if you had ever tested it on the n10?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tested it on a htc phone running Froyo, I get the same issue, when I go back to the preview I've lost the orientation and it's stretched etc.  It's like it's not being configured or something

Comment: "I'm wondering if you had ever tested it on the n10?" -- no, because I discontinued that camera book chapter ~18 months ago, just restoring it this past Monday, having switched to CWAC-Camera.

Comment: @CommonsWare if you could help me out on this i'd appreciate it, I'm trying to keep the camera part of my project v simple and your new lib looks a little too complicated...

Comment: Using CWAC-Camera is a matter of putting the JAR in your project, showing a `CameraFragment` for the preview, and calling `takePicture()` when you want to take a picture. Everything else is optional. If that's "too complicated", then so is the old code of mine that you are trying to use. Furthermore, that old code was simply an example out of a book. Working directly with the camera is seriously complicated, which is why I switched to working on a library that I can maintain without necessarily having to explain every last line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone like me (learning the ropes) comes across this same issue, what my problem was I had added

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

in order to rotate the preview to portrait.  My problem was, I had called this in the wrong place, I now call it in the `onResume()` method.

A simple fix in the end...thanks everyone